# When I run tflite file, it just shows "aborted (core dumped)"

Tags: tensorflow-lite

When I use tf version 1.13.1 to convert pb to tflite, it shows ***dim not matched*** error, but when I use 1.14 to convert, it succeeds to save the tflite file. But when I use the test code in the doc, it just shows *core dumped*.

Here's is the output:

converted with 1.13.1

```
 ture_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA  
2019-09-23 14:33:07.069746: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3696000000 Hz  
2019-09-23 14:33:07.072588: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x564ecd24a790 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:  
2019-09-23 14:33:07.072658: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>  
Ignore 'tcmalloc: large alloc' warnings.  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "pb-to-tflite.py", line 9, in <module>  
    tflite_model = converter.convert()  
  File "/home/dm/anaconda3/envs/s-t3/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 455, in convert  
    **converter_kwargs)  
  File "/home/dm/anaconda3/envs/s-t3/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 442, in toco_convert_impl  
    input_data.SerializeToString())  
  File "/home/dm/anaconda3/envs/s-t3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 205, in toco_convert_protos  
    "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.  
2019-09-23 14:33:21.269591: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 529 operators, 854 arrays (0 quantized)  
2019-09-23 14:33:21.275653: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After Removing unused ops pass 1: 527 operators, 849 arrays (0 quantized)  
2019-09-23 14:33:21.283483: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 527 operators, 849 arrays (0 quantized)  
2019-09-23 14:33:21.330461: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:117] Check failed: dim_x == dim_y (512 vs. 10)Dimensions must match  
Aborted (core dumped)
```

converted by 1.14

```
2019-09-23 14:38:45.285133: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:716] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize  
2019-09-23 14:38:45.285519: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:718]   constant folding: Graph size after: 440 nodes (-112), 631 edges (-112), time = 213.324ms.  
2019-09-23 14:38:45.285580: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:718]   constant folding: Graph size after: 440 nodes (0), 631 edges (0), time = 54.184ms.
```

and when I use the code below to test

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print(input_details)
print(output_details)
# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
print(input_data.shape)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()
# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

it just shows

```
 [{'name': 'input', 'index': 95, 'shape': array([  1, 257, 400,   1], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]  
[{'name': 'lambda_1/l2_normalize', 'index': 96, 'shape': array([  1, 512], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]  
(1, 257, 400, 1)  
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and I could use netron to open the generated tflite file
[the network structure it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlSAn.png)

could somebody give me some help?

Comment: It's difficult to debug without seeing how you converted the model and the model file itself. Can you post the script? Also, did you build as debug or opt? It might be best to open an issue on Github, since this might be something particular to your model,  rather than a general  question for the community.

Comment: thanks, I have found it's because i use keras to defind my own layer, and in this layer i use add_weight() function to add trainable variable in this layers, when the tflite  running invoke() , it will broken when reading this variable. here is the model code i use(https://github.com/WeidiXie/VGG-Speaker-Recognition). i still finding a way to solve this problem. @talumbau